# How can i add list data in my object in visual studio 2005?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Below codes run perfectly but i want to re generate simply

```
 static void YeniMethodListele()
        {
            Calısan calisan = new Calısan(){ ID=1, Ad="xxx", SoyAd="yyy"};
            List<Calısan> myList = new List<Calısan>();
            myList.Add(calisan);
            MyCalısan myCalısan = new MyCalısan() { list = myList };
            //myCalısan.list.Add(calisan);

            foreach (Calısan item in myCalısan.list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Ad.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

   public class Calısan
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Ad { get; set; }
        public string SoyAd { get; set; }

    }

   public class MyCalısan
    {
        public List<Calısan> list { get; set; }
        public MyCalısan()
        {
            list = new List<Calısan>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: MyCalısan myCalısan = new MyCalısan() { list.Add( Ad ="fgdhfh", SoyAd="bnvbnvbn" };

Comment: what is it? Is it something what you would like to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of a couple of ways to create the list a little more simply. Note the small change to the `Calısan` object to give it a default constructor and an overloaded constructor.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ////Calısan calisan = new Calısan() { ID = 1, Ad = "xxx", SoyAd = "yyy" };
            MyCalısan myCalısan = new MyCalısan();

            //option 1:
            //==========
            myCalısan.list.AddRange(new[] { new Calısan() { ID = 1, Ad = "xxx", SoyAd = "yyyy" }, new Calısan() { ID = 2, Ad = "blah", SoyAd = "jiggy" } });

            //option 2:
            //=========
            myCalısan.list.AddRange(new[] { new Calısan(1, "xxx", "yyy"), new Calısan(2, "blah", "jiggy") });

            ////myCalısan.list.Add(calisan);

            foreach (Calısan item in myCalısan.list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Ad.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Calısan
    {
        public Calısan() { }

                            public Calısan(int id, string ad, string soyad)
    {
        ID = id;
        Ad = ad;
        SoyAd = soyad;
    }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Ad { get; set; }
        public string SoyAd { get; set; }

    }

    public class MyCalısan
    {
        public List<Calısan> list { get; set; }
        public MyCalısan()
        {
            list = new List<Calısan>();
        }
    }
}
```